# AS3 3D Tween not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have an animation that is created in flash, I have used the 3d tween changing many angles and rotations over 60 frames
playing this animation works fine by its self, The "snowy Screen is the 3d tween"Below is the object rotating

[image]

When I load this SWF into another Main SWF the 3d tween is ignored.Below 
is the problem[image]

Im hoping some one can explain if this is a glitch of some sort..
I have exported into different flash versions and have created different loader classes to try and find a solution. 
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code used? It's possible that it's not firing in the loaded swf because it references the "_root" value or some-such reference that no longer exists in the Main SWF.

Comment: '_root" is as2, everything is firing correctly just the movie when loaded in a main all 3d tweens ignored, I have tried several loaderclasses "all failing" also this animation consist of no action script

Comment: It looks fine on the site. Do you have any code samples? hard to debug without them. Can you place a "trace" statement in the area of code you're dealing with and see if that fires from the Main SWF?

Comment: yeah this one iv loaded up is good but if i open the fla and resave the swf and replace it it comes up with the glitch.i have googled around and my conclusion is its just one of those glitches and is hard to pin point the problem.so i have have just restarted the project from scratch and will render new assets, maybe plan my website better, its a shame theres no simple answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered this before and it killed me. If you load one 3D tween into a different SWF the parent SWF will control the perspective (there can only be one perspective per SWF at least as of Flash 10 player). You will need to set the perspective values identically in both the loaded SWF and the parent SWF. This one aspect of Flash 3D turned me off so much I do not use the feature at all anymore. This even goes for different assets dynamically parented together.

Comment: im assuming this is correct but im with you iv decided to throw it away aswell and come with alternative so far looking into 3d engines than just load a child swf to complete the task of the animation.